# Only one px class in tailwind works

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an issue with tailwind classes. I am trying to change padding on the x axis using .px class however, the only class that works is px-4 all other px classes resets the padding to 0. Anyone know what the issue could be?

I post my html with the tailwind classes if that helps.

```html
<header class="bg-gray-900">
    <div class="mx-auto px-4 ">
        <nav class=" px-4 py-6 flex items-center justify-between">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="text-white text-3xl font-bold" href="{% url 'home' %}">
                LOGO
            </a>

            <!-- Nav Links -->
            <ul class="hidden md:flex font-semibold space-x-12">
                <li><a class="text-white hover:text-gray-400" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-white hover:text-gray-400" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-white hover:text-gray-400" href="{% url 'booking' %}">Booking</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-white hover:text-gray-400" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Hamburger Menu (Visible on Mobile) -->
            <button class="md:hidden navbar-burger text-white">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 hover:text-gray-200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I just tested it with a Tailwind cdn and all `px` classes are working and showing the changes.

Comment: You may also just need to hit the browser refresh button, depending on your hot-reloading setup.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind works by generating a file with all used classes to reduce bloat on your site once its live. If your making these changes on the live server its likely that the generated file isnt being updated.

Whenever I use tailwind with my projects I always work in a local environment to ensure the `npm run watch` command can see my changes and update the compiled CSS.

If for some reason I am unable to work in a local environment I would just use plain css to make small changes or use tailwind classes that have been used elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I may have run into similar problems before, where just in time compiler isn't updating the css with some classes used in my template. All I did was ask Tailwind to look into files in that directory and voila, new classes became functional!

Therefore, go into your tailwind.config.js and look at the `content` array. See if you're asking tailwind compiler to scan files in the directory where this markup is.
Also, don't forget to `run npm run dev` or `npm run watch` as the case may be, to enable live compilation.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (in a Laravel-based project, yours might differ):

```
    content: [
    './resources/**/*.antlers.html',
    "./resources/**/**/*.antlers.html",
    "./resources/**/**/**/*.antlers.html",
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
    './content/**/*.md'
   ]
```

More on this on the official documentation here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

By the way, I tested your code with px-10 and px-16 on Tailwind CDN. Working good!

Hope this helps to solve your problem!

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your answer**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.